# Another alternating-case in-a-string in Python 3.+

Tags: python, loops, case, uppercase, lowercase

I'm very new to Python and am trying to understand how to manipulate strings.

What I want to do is change a string by removing the spaces and alternating the case from upper to lower, IE "This is harder than I thought it would be" to "ThIsIsHaRdErThAnItHoUgHtItWoUlDbE"

I've cobbled together a code to remove the spaces (heavily borrowed from here):

```
string1 = input("Ask user for something.")
nospace = ""
for a in string1:
      if a == " ":
         pass
      else:
         nospace=nospace+a
```

... but just can't get my head around the caps/lower case part. There are several similar issues on this site and I've tried amending a few of them, with no joy. I realise I need to define a range and iterate through it, but that's where I draw a blank.

```
for c in nospace[::]:
    d = ""
    c = nospace[:1].lower()
    d = d + c
    c = nospace[:1].upper
print d
```

All I am getting is a column of V's. I'm obviously getting this very wrong. Please can someone advise where? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cutesie way to do this:

```
>>> s = "This is harder than I thought it would be"
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> funcs = cycle([str.upper, str.lower])
>>> ''.join(next(funcs)(c) for c in s if c != ' ')
'ThIsIsHaRdErThAnItHoUgHtItWoUlDbE'
>>>
```

Or, as suggested by Moses in the comments, you can use `str.isspace`, which will take care of not just a single space `' '`

```
>>> ''.join(next(funcs)(c) for c in s if not c.isspace())
'ThIsIsHaRdErThAnItHoUgHtItWoUlDbE'
```

This approach only does a single pass on the string. Although, a two-pass method is likely performant enough.

Now, if you were starting with a `nospace` string, the best way is to convert to some mutable type (e.g. a `list`) and use slice-assignment notation. It's a little bit inefficient because it builds intermediate data structures, but slicing is *fast* in Python, so it may be quite performant. You have to `''.join` at the end, to bring it back to a string:

```
>>> nospace
'ThisisharderthanIthoughtitwouldbe'
>>> nospace = list(nospace)
>>> nospace[0::2] = map(str.upper, nospace[0::2])
>>> nospace[1::2] = map(str.lower, nospace[1::2])
>>> ''.join(nospace)
'ThIsIsHaRdErThAnItHoUgHtItWoUlDbE'
>>>
```

Comment: You could use `if not c.isspace()` which is going to be more faster.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye nice! And that works with all whitespace too!

Answer (score 0):

So your 2nd loop is where you're breaking it, because the original list isn't being shortened, the c=nospace[:1] grabs the first character of the string and that's the only character that's ever printed. So a solution would be as follows.

```
string1 = str(input("Ask user for something."))

nospace = ''.join(string1.split(' '))

for i in range(0, len(nospace)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(nospace[i].upper(), end="")
    else:
        print(nospace[i].lower(), end="")
```

Could also replace the if/else statement with a [ternary opperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

```
for i in range(0, len(nospace)):
    print(nospace[i].upper() if (i % 2 == 0) else nospace[i].lower(), end='')
```

Final way using enumerate as commented about

```
for i, c in enumerate(nospace):
    print(c.upper() if (i % 2 == 0) else c.lower(), end='')
```

Comment: Instead of iterating over `range(0, len(something))` it is nicer to use `range(len(something))`. And if you are going to be using the index *and* the element, you actually just want enumerate: `for i, e in enumerate(something)`

Comment: I knew about the range thing, but since he said new to python thought I wouldn't skip that. However wasn't aware of the enumerate bit thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do everything at once. Don't. Break your program into steps.

1. Read the string.
2. Remove the spaces from the string (as @A.Sherif just demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939203/871910))
3. Go over the string character by character. If the character is in an odd position, convert it to uppercase. Otherwise, convert to lowercase.

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing things in a single pass :) Especially if you take advantage of Python's beautiful, expressive and effective iterator constructs.

Answer (score -2):

## Code

The following python script converts strings in any case into alternating-case

```python
import io # input output library 

def to_alternating_case(istr:str):
    strm = io.StringIO()

    # iidx..... input index
    # ich  .... input character 
    for idx, ich in enumerate(istr):
        if (idx % 2) == 0:
            print(ich.lower(), end="", file=strm)
        else: # index is odd such as 1, 3, 5, 7, 9...
        print(ich.upper(), end="", file=strm)
        
    end_result = strm.getvalue()
    strm.close() # prevent a memory leak
```

---

## Test Run

```python
# input string
istr   = "ATTACK THE DRAGON WITH SWORD"

#
end_result = to_alternating_case(istr)

#
print(end_result)
```

---

## Test Results

```
# input string
istr   = "ATTACK THE DRAGON WITH SWORD"

# output string
ostr = "aTtAcK ThE DrAgOn wItH SwOrD"
```

Comment: This does not remove spaces as required, and does not alternative casing when two letters are separated by a space.